# Cannot access some controllers in a Spring Boot and Jersey application

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jersey, spring-boot

I have a small problem to access some controllers. When I send a request to `/`, I a get an HTTP 404, and the same for the `movies` path.

```
package com.emo.server; 


@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.emo.server", "com.emo.server.controller"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
}


@Path("/")
public String home() {
    return "Hello World";
}


@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http            
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/movies").permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/test")
            .access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId("test");
    }

}


@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("my-trusted-client")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .resourceIds("test")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60)
                .and()
                .withClient("my-client-with-secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read")
                .resourceIds("test")
                .secret("secret");
        // @formatter:on
    }

}
```

A part of the MovieController:

```
package com.emo.server.controller;

@Component
@Path("/movies")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MovieController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MovieController.class);

    @GET
    @Path("/")
    public Response getMovies() {
        System.out.println("Just a test after ....");
    }
```

From this one, I hope a get just a test after, but I got a 404.

The part of the console:

```
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< X-Application-Context: application
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Wed, 07 Oct 2015 19:15:20 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"timestamp":1444245320491,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/"}
```

A picture of my project:

[image]

I've tried to registrer my controllers with the `resourceConfig`, but it happens the same thing.

I can access some endpoints like `oauth/token`, `health`,... I use spring-boot and jersey as REST-framework with java 8.

Comment: Are you mixing Spring Boot and Jersey because you *do* know what you're doing, right?

Comment: hummm. I use jersey as REST-Framework. But i try it without with Jersey, with the default REST-Spring (Request-Mapping), but i got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your controller annotations to something like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/movies", produces="application/json)
public class MovieController{

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public MyResponseObject getMovies(){
        //you can return a POJO object if you are using a Jackson Mapper
        return new MyResponseObject("foo", "bar");
    }

}
```

Comment: don't help me. i thought, the was jersey, i removed all the jersey dependencies and nothing.

Comment: Why dont you try this by xml config?

Comment: i removde jersey and it works now. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33026968/spring-boot-org-springframework-beans-factory-beancreationexception-could-not-a/33088873#33088873

Comment: @emoleumassi, can you please paste your solution?