# spring boot org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field:

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm starting with spring-boot and i have some configuration problems. I cannot autowire some services. I get an BeanCreationException.

My Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.x.server", basePackageClasses = { OAuth2ServerConfiguration.class,
        AController.class, BController.class })
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Application().configure(new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)).run(args);
    }
}
```

hier the structur of my project:

```
----com.x.server
--------Application.java
----com.x.server.controller
--------AController.java
--------BController.java
----other packages
----com.x.server.service
--------WYXService
--------ABCService
----com.x.server.service.serviceImpl
--------WYXServiceImpl
--------ABCServiceImpl
```

The interface my service

```
public interface WYXService<T> {

    public void setClazz(final Class<T> clazzToSet);
    public void createEntity(T t);
    public void removeEntity(T t);
}
```

And the implementation

```
@Transactional
@Service("wyxService")
public class WYXServiceImpl<T> implements WYXService<T>
```

Hier is the controller where i autowire the service:

```
@Path("/test")
@Component
@Controller
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class BController {

    @Autowired
    WYXService wyxService;
```

the error of the console:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.x.server.service.WYXService com.x.server.controller.BController.wyxService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.x.server.service.WYXService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.x.server.service.WYXService ] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 27 more
```

when i remove the two controllers from compenentscan, i don't have this error but i need to scan those controllers to access the endpoints.

has someone any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried to include the relevant class into basePackageClasses and see if that picks it up?

Comment: just a suggestion can you please try changing @Service("wyxService") to @Service("WYXService ")

Comment: @Aeseir, which relevant class do you mean? The controller? i did with componentscan. @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.x.server", basePackageClasses = { OAuth2ServerConfiguration.class,
        AController.class, BController.class })

Comment: WYXService class. I have had a problem where it didn't get picked up by basePackages but when i added it directly under basePackageClasses it picked it up no problems. Also can you put in the whole stack error begining to end as there could be something hiding that is causing a cascade failure.

Answer (score 2):

I remove the jersey dependency:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

and then I added the sprint-boot-starter-web dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

i just remove the Jersey dependency and only work with the native REST-api (RequestMapping) from spring. And it works. I think, spring-boot and jersey don't work good together.