# Can't serve static content with Spring Boot and Jersey 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, jersey-2.0, swagger-ui

Is there any way of making Spring Boot with Jersey serve static content? I've been through a series of tutorials and code samples on integrating Swagger into a Spring Boot's application. I can make it deliver the basic swagger.json, but I can't make Swagger UI work.

I can't even make it deliver a simple `hello.txt` static file.

The relevant parts of my pom.xml are:

```
<!--Spring Boot-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- Jersey -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Swagger -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7</version>
</dependency>
```

And my code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"com.xxxx"})
public class AdminApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(AdminApplication.class)
                .run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean jerseyServlet() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new ServletContainer(), "/*");
        registration.addInitParameter(ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS, JerseyConfig.class.getName());
        return registration;
    }
}




package com.xxxxxx.admin.config;
import com.xxxxxx.admin.resource.Status;
import org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.scope.RequestContextFilter;    
import io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig;

public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(RequestContextFilter.class);
        packages("com"); // TODO needs more detailed level
        register(LoggingFilter.class);
        // Validation
        this.property(ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true);
        this.property(ServerProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR, true);
        configureSwagger();
    }

    private void configureSwagger() {
        register(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
        register(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class);
        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.0");
        beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
        beanConfig.setHost("localhost:8080");
        beanConfig.setBasePath("/"); // tried other things like "/api", but doesn't change anything
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage("com.xxxxxx.admin");
        beanConfig.setPrettyPrint(true);
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
    }

}



//other imports
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;

@Service
@Path("/status")
@Api(value = "status", description = "Check status")
public class Status {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation("Return status")
    public Response status() {
        return Response.ok("Up").build();
    }
}
```

I also tried making Jersey run as a filter (with `spring.jersey.type=filter`) and changing Jersey's servlet pattern as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35170684/5877773), but that doesn't seem to affect anything.

```
@ApplicationPath("/rootPath")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
```

I have a hello.txt file under /src/main/resources/public and Swagger UI's static files under /src/main/resources/public/swagger.

As I said, my application works fine, and GET http://localhost:8080/swagger.json shows me the plain json documentation, but both http://localhost:8080/hello.txt and http://localhost:8080/swagger/index.html return 404.

I'm using Jersey 2.8 and Spring Boot 1.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I also tried changing Jersey's servlet pattern
>
> ```
> @ApplicationPath("/rootPath")
> public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
> ```

The way you are configuring your app, the `@ApplicationPath` doesn't matter. The reason it worked for [this answer you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35170684/2587435), is because the Spring Boot auto configuration sets the servlet mapping when it extracts the `@ApplicationPath` value from your resource config.

You are currently not using the `ServletRegistrationBean` provided by Spring Boot, that accomplishes this. If you goal, by using your own `ServletRegistrationBean`, was so that you can register your `ResourceConfig`, you could've have done the same simply by either

1. Annotating your `ResourceConfig` with `@Component` to make it a Spring bean, or
2. Make it a Spring bean in your configuration class

   ```
   @Bean
   public ResourceConfig config() {
       return new JerseyConfig();
   }
   ```

Spring Boot will then inject your `ResourceConfig` into the `JerseyAutoConfiguration`, where it will get the `@ApplicationPath` value (if present) on the `ResourceConfig`, and use it to register its own `ServletRegistrationBean`.

You can see the [`JerseyAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jersey/JerseyAutoConfiguration.java) to get an idea of everything you get for free, when you let Spring Boot handle the configuration.

Of if you want to keep your current `SpringRegistrationBean`, just change the path you are using. You are using `/*`, which is mentioned to be the problem in the linked answer. So just change to `/rooPath/*` if that's what you want.

Comment: That's a great answer, thanks! But there is something weird. I set `spring.jersey.type=filter` and `spring.jersey.application-path=rootPath`, and everything works nicely: static content is served and the app endpoints are moved to `rootPath/` and reply correctly. But If I only set `spring.jersey.type=filter` and not  `spring.jersey.application-path`, the static content is no longer reachable. According to option 1 in your linked answer, setting jersey to run as a filter should be enough. What am I missing?

Comment: Because you still need to set the property `ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404` to `true`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29670751/2587435)

Comment: I forgot to mention that you were right in that I added my own `ServletRegistrationBean` to registe `ResourceConfi`g. I followed your advice and annotated `ResourceConfig` with `@Component` and no longer use my own `ServletRegistrationBean`.

Comment: Ok, so that means that I can't possibly have the static content and the jersey resources under the same path, right?

Comment: No you can, but you need to tell Jersey (filter) to forward the request when it can't find your static content. That's what the above property does. But with a servlet, no you can't. It needs to be a filter

Comment: Added that property, but still doesn't work. Could it be caused by some other filter (I'm thinking of `LoggingFilter`) adding an entity to the response? `ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404`'s documentation says _...and a 404 response with no entity body is returned from either the runtime or the application..._ And the responses that I get have both a 404 header and a "HTTP 404 Not Found" body.

Comment: No the logging filter is not a problem. AFAIK it doesn't add an entity to the response. I use it all the time for development. Are you sure you set the Spring Boot property `spring.jersey.type=filter`? This works for me all the time

Comment: If you want to put together a minimal (github) project that I can test out, I'll check it out, but I can't reproduce the problem on my end.

Comment: Found it: I needed to remove the `entity()` part of `return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity(exception.getMessage()).build()` in my `ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException>.toResponse`. Again, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

It looks the same as a common issue when using Spring MVC. A servlet container is required per servlet specification to implement a default server with lowest priority that is able to serve static content located outside WEB-INF folder.
Unfortunately, you are mapping Jersey servlet to `"/*"`, meaning that every URL will be submitted to Jersey, and Jersey does not know what to do with static URLs.

So what can be (easily) done?

- map the Jersey servlet to a subpath (say `/api`) and move all you controllers there:

  ```
  ServletRegistrationBean registration =
      new ServletRegistrationBean(new ServletContainer(), "/api/*");
  ...
  beanConfig.setBasePath("/api/");
  ```

  and ask `GET http://localhost:8080/api/swagger.json`
- only map the servlet to `*.json` URLs:

  ```
  ServletRegistrationBean registration =
      new ServletRegistrationBean(new ServletContainer(), "*.json");
  ```