# Spring Boot + Jersey + view controller not working together

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jersey

I'm experimenting with Spring a bit. With use of Spring Boot I have prepared an application that allows basic CRUD operations on my entity objects.

I have tested it in two ways - first by writing a standard Controller:

```
@Controller
public class AdminController
{
    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDao;

    @RequestMapping(value={"admin", "admin/list"})
    public String list(Model m)
    {
        List<User> users;
        users = (List<User>) userDao.findAll();
        m.addAttribute("users", users);
        return "admin/index";
    }

    (...)

}
```

With Thymeleaf-flavoured views - working like a charm

Secondly, I've written RESTful resource with Jersey:

```
@Path("/user")
public class UserResource
{
    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDao;

    @POST
    @Path("/list")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public List<User> list()
    {
        List<User> users;
        users = (List<User>) userDao.findAll();
        return users;
    }

    (...)

}
```

That's also working, but... not together.
Once I have My UserResource registered in JerseyConfiguration - I cannot access the standard controller anymore. When I comment out the registration of resource - the REST resources cease to respond, but the controller and the views are accessible again.

Why is it happening so? What am I missing?

Comment: Are you getting 404 with Spring controllers? It's possible [this is the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35170462/2587435)

Comment: thank you peeskillet - that's exactly the case!