# Spring REST Controller not mapped

Tags: java, spring, rest, controller

I'm trying to create à Rest controller that listen on "/login" I have defined the code bellow but when I open http://localhost:8080/login I get a 404 error...
Please help :)

Here is my package structure:

```
com.my.package
   |_ Application.java
   |_ controller
          |_ LoginController
```

**My Application:**

```
@ComponentScan("com.my.package.controller")
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**My Rest controller:**

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public @ResponseBody String getLogin(){
        return "{}";
    }
}
```

Comment: bad spelling in stackoverflow -_-"

Comment: You need `@Configuration` on your `Application` class (or trade all of the annotations for `@SpringBootApplication`).

Comment: I have tryed with @SpringBootApplication but nothing :/

Comment: What packages are everything in? Can you confirm in the logs whether a mapping for `/login` is being registered?

Comment: I have edited my package structure

Comment: can you paste stack trace in console when you access the url

Comment: Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot: Cannot access REST Controller on localhost (404)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318107/spring-boot-cannot-access-rest-controller-on-localhost-404)

Answer (score 6):

The controller class should be in a folder of the Application class or in the lower folder.

So, if the application class is in package `com.company.app`, then the controller class should be in package `com.company.app` or in `com.company.app.*.` Let say the controller class is in `com.company.controller`, it will not mapped since its not in same package or child package of application class.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this annotations in your init class of your springBoot App

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.my.package")
public class WebAppInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        SpringApplication.run(WebAppInitializer.class, args);
    }
```

}

Comment: This is not working :/
I'm sure there is something else I'm missing :/

Comment: Those annotations are *exactly* equivalent to `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Took me a full day to realize that my controller package name was "controller" instead of "com.my.controller". @ComponenetScan("controller") fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when it makes no sense why the mapping is not working, just change the server port so something different than 8080.

ie. in the application.properties or yml, server.port=8081