# 404-not-found-while-running-spring-boot-rest-api

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

While running springboot restservice application got 404 error.  I am using spring boot, jersey rest. I have tried GET requests *`http://localhost:8080/dunames`* but not able to resolve. Please help.

**Model Class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "du")
public class duname {


    private String duname;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id; 
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public duname()
    {

    }

    public duname(String duname, int id)
    {
    this.duname=duname; 
    this.id=id;
    }


    public String getDuname() {
        return duname;
    }

    public void setDuname(String duname) {
        this.duname = duname;
    }
}
```

**Service Class:**

```
public class duservice {

    @Autowired
    private durepo durepository;

    public List<duname> getAlldu()
    {
        List<duname> dunames=new ArrayList<duname>();
        durepository.findAll()
        .forEach(dunames::add);
        return dunames;
    }

    public void addDu(duname dunames)
    {
        durepository.save(dunames);
    }

    public duname getDu(int id)
    {
        return durepository.findOne(id);
    }

    public void deleteDu(int id)
    {
        durepository.delete(id);
    }

    public void updateDu(int id, duname dunames)
    {
        durepository.save(dunames);
    }
}
```

**Controller class:**

```
    @RestController
public class ducontroller {


    @Autowired
    private duservice duService;

    private final Logger log=(java.util.logging.Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(ducontroller.class);


    @RequestMapping("/dunames")
    public List<duname> getAlldu()
    {
          log.info("Starting");
    return duService.getAlldu();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/duname/{id}")
    public duname getdu(@PathVariable int id)
    {
        return duService.getDu(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value="/dunames")
    public void addDuname(@RequestBody duname dunames)
    {
        duService.addDu(dunames);
    }
```

**Repository:**

```
public interface durepo extends CrudRepository<duname,Integer> {


}
```

**Main Class:**

```
 @SpringBootApplication
public class DuaddApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DuaddApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Pom File:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.du</groupId>
    <artifactId>duadd</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>duadd</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**Application Properties:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:2280/todo
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
server.port=8080
```

Some console output:

```
2017-10-26 11:06:08.952  INFO 4552 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-10-26 11:06:08.975  INFO 4552 --- [           main] com.soprasteria.du.DuaddApplication      : Started DuaddApplication in 7.096 seconds (JVM running for 7.633)
2017-10-26 11:06:32.779  INFO 4552 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-10-26 11:06:32.779  INFO 4552 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-10-26 11:06:32.800  INFO 4552 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 21 ms
```

Comment: Yes i know but can't figure out where i went wrong.

Comment: According to your console output, it seems that the method `getAlldu()` didn't be called. So, did you get any message after invoking `http://localhost:8080/dunames`?

Comment: What does your `web.xml` look like?

Comment: @LHCHIN Yes it is not called. I got the 404 message.

Comment: @Wabi It does not have web.xml . It is spring boot application

Comment: It is weird that I didn't see any request mapping information in your console output after application startup. Normally, it should print something like `Mapped "{[/dunames]}" onto public xxx.xxx.ducontroller`.

Comment: @LHCHIN Yes. I have tried many things but don't know what went wrong

Comment: Another question, why you need to add the dependency of `spring-boot-starter-jersey` into your pom file?

Comment: @LHCHIN Yes that's of no use. I removed it.

Comment: I have imported your source into my STS IDE with small modification, and it worked well. I can perform selection and insertion via the services. What I have modified are: (1) 
 Use h2 database with configuring property by `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE` (2) Add `@Component` to `duservice` class.

Comment: I added @Component to my duservice class but stll not working.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I got the solution. It was due to package visibility. 
Main class was not able to find package in which controller class is present. 
So, I added all classes under the same package. You can also place application class one level up.

Got help from below link:

[Spring Boot: Cannot access REST Controller on localhost (404)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318107/spring-boot-cannot-access-rest-controller-on-localhost-404)

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people said file management but I found my issue to be not including a path for my `@GetMapping`

For example, instead of `@GetMapping`
I had: `@GetMapping("/")`

This issue held me back so much and though might not solve yours's, I'm sure and hoping will help someone.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is serval reason associated with error 404, in my case I created a spring boot starter project in eclipse and forget to include spring-boot-starter-web in my project .I solved the issue after adding dependency in  pom.xml

> org.springframework.boot         spring-boot-starter-web