# spring RequestMappingHandlerMapping not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapping

I´m starting with Spring Boot for that I´m following a tutorial. In the tutorial, they created the controller with the @RequestMapping and GET method, once they have run the application, in the console is displayed something like this:

> s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/rooms], methods
>   = GET}" onto java.util.List<..//more lines

But in my case I got an error:

> s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto
>   public
>   org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity>
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)

Why the Mapping is not created?

This is the controller:

```
package com.frankmoley.london.data.webservice;

import com.frankmoley.london.data.entity.Room;
import com.frankmoley.london.data.repository.RoomRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class RoomController {

    @Autowired
    private RoomRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(value="/rooms", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    List<Room> findAll(@RequestParam(required=false) String roomNumber){

       List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<>();

        if(null==roomNumber){

            Iterable<Room> results = this.repository.findAll();
            results.forEach(room-> {rooms.add(room);});
        }else{

            Room room = this.repository.findByNumber(roomNumber);
            if(null!=room) {
                rooms.add(room);
            }
        }
        return rooms;
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
package com.frankmoley.london.data.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ROOM")
public class Room {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ROOM_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "ROOM_NUMBER")
    private String number;
    @Column(name = "BED_INFO")
    private String info;

//getters and setters
}
```

Repository:

```
package com.frankmoley.london.data.repository;

import com.frankmoley.london.data.entity.Room;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface RoomRepository extends CrudRepository<Room, Long> {
    Room findByNumber(String number);

}
```

Comment: How many controllers are there in your project?
 Can you show the complete error stacktrace?

Comment: only one the RoomController

Comment: [this might give you some idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31318789/2749470)

Comment: I added the line @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = RoomController.class) in below the @SpringBootApplication line. But then I got an error in the controler. In the private RoomRepository repository; the "repository" reference is underlined in red, "Could not autowire. No neans of "RoomRepository" type found

Comment: @SergVasylchak I just added it

Comment: solved! , The SpringBootApplication, was in the wrong package. It was in com.frankmoley.reservations, and I moved into the upper package.  com.frankmoley. Thank you for your suggestions

Comment: Just to mention: `Mapped "{[/error]}"` doesn't mean you got an error. That's a mapping that redirects your application to e.g. `http://localhost:8080/error` after an error has happened in some situations. I'm just not sure which errors cause this redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Following are my logs:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.8.RELEASE)

2019-09-09 21:41:37.074  INFO 25569 --- [           main] SpringRest.spring_rest.Application       : Starting Application on prashant-ubuntu with PID 25569 (/home/prashant/workspace/egen/spring-rest/target/spring-rest-1.0.0.jar started by prashant in /home/prashant/workspace/egen/spring-rest/target)
2019-09-09 21:41:37.077  INFO 25569 --- [           main] SpringRest.spring_rest.Application       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-09-09 21:41:37.715  INFO 25569 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-09-09 21:41:37.796  INFO 25569 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 68ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
2019-09-09 21:41:38.389  INFO 25569 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d6eeeeff] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-09-09 21:41:38.696  INFO 25569 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-09-09 21:41:38.735  INFO 25569 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-09-09 21:41:38.735  INFO 25569 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.24]
2019-09-09 21:41:38.837  INFO 25569 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-09-09 21:41:38.837  INFO 25569 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1701 ms
2019-09-09 21:41:39.124  INFO 25569 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-09-09 21:41:39.415  INFO 25569 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-09-09 21:41:39.463  INFO 25569 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-09-09 21:41:39.525  INFO 25569 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.11.Final}
2019-09-09 21:41:39.526  INFO 25569 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-09-09 21:41:39.662  INFO 25569 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-09-09 21:41:39.866  INFO 25569 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2019-09-09 21:41:40.463  INFO 25569 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2019-09-09 21:41:40.559  INFO 25569 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-09-09 21:41:41.041  INFO 25569 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-09-09 21:41:41.114  WARN 25569 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2019-09-09 21:41:41.380  INFO 25569 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-09-09 21:41:41.382  INFO 25569 --- [           main] SpringRest.spring_rest.Application       : Started Application in 4.703 seconds (JVM running for 5.103)
2019-09-09 21:42:03.922  INFO 25569 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-09-09 21:42:03.922  INFO 25569 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-09-09 21:42:03.934  INFO 25569 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 12 ms
Hibernate: select employee0_.id as id1_0_, employee0_.email as email2_0_, employee0_.name as name3_0_, employee0_.salary as salary4_0_ from employee employee0_
```

you can clearly see that there aren't any references of RequestMappingHandlerMapping

But still the service is hosted at "/".

I have used the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/employees/springEntityManagerJpa
```

With other spring application which is not spring boot, the URL is as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/spring-rest/api/employees/springEntityManagerJpa
```

I assume your is the similar case. May be the service is up, but you are providing the wrong endpoints. Just remove the context path. In my case I removed `/spring-rest/api`

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: may be bcoz you upgraded soring boot versionhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405474/add-context-path-to-spring-boot-application