# RequestMapping of SpringBoot Not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am learning Spring Boot for building Applications. I am trying to build my first Spring Boot Application with a controller in different package as application. Tomcat instance comes up but request does not reach RestController registered for the URI.

Following is the controller class:

```
package com.spring.controllers;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/abc")
    public String getHi() {
        System.out.println("End Point hit");
        return "Hi";
    }
}
```

Following is the application class:

```
package com.spring.boot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.spring.controllers"})
public class SpringBootMain {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootMain.class, args);
    }
}
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>RandomProjects</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringBoot</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.spring.boot.SpringBootMain</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

Logs when tomcat starts:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.6.RELEASE)

2017-12-25 16:41:16.236  INFO 50314 --- [BootMain.main()] com.spring.boot.SpringBootMain           : Starting SpringBootMain on f45c89be9049.ant.amazon.com with PID 50314 (/Users/sumt/Desktop/Work/RandomWork/RandomProjects/target/classes started by sumt in /Users/sumt/Desktop/Work/RandomWork/RandomProjects)
2017-12-25 16:41:16.244  INFO 50314 --- [BootMain.main()] com.spring.boot.SpringBootMain           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-12-25 16:41:16.408  INFO 50314 --- [BootMain.main()] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7bbcce75: startup date [Mon Dec 25 16:41:16 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-12-25 16:41:18.279  INFO 50314 --- [BootMain.main()] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-12-25 16:41:18.295  INFO 50314 --- [BootMain.main()] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-12-25 16:41:18.297  INFO 50314 --- [BootMain.main()] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.16
2017-12-25 16:41:18.402  INFO 50314 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-12-25 16:41:18.402  INFO 50314 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2056 ms
2017-12-25 16:41:18.560  INFO 50314 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-12-25 16:41:18.564  INFO 50314 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-25 16:41:18.565  INFO 50314 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-25 16:41:18.565  INFO 50314 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-25 16:41:18.566  INFO 50314 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-25 16:41:18.920  INFO 50314 --- [BootMain.main()] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7bbcce75: startup date [Mon Dec 25 16:41:16 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-12-25 16:41:19.005  INFO 50314 --- [BootMain.main()] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-12-25 16:41:19.007  INFO 50314 --- [BootMain.main()] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-12-25 16:41:19.041  INFO 50314 --- [BootMain.main()] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-12-25 16:41:19.041  INFO 50314 --- [BootMain.main()] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-12-25 16:41:19.084  INFO 50314 --- [BootMain.main()] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-12-25 16:41:19.323  INFO 50314 --- [BootMain.main()] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-12-25 16:41:19.407  INFO 50314 --- [BootMain.main()] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-12-25 16:41:19.413  INFO 50314 --- [BootMain.main()] com.spring.boot.SpringBootMain           : Started SpringBootMain in 3.889 seconds (JVM running for 6.196)
```

I have added base package scan and even tried with `@ComponentScan` annotation, but the result is same when I hit URL (http://localhost:8080/abc):

There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Did anyone else face the same issue? Please suggest as how did you solve this.

Comment: how are you reaching the controller ? with which url?

Comment: URL that I am reaching is - http://localhost:8080/abc

Comment: when the application starts, spring-boot lists all the requestsmapping. Do you see the mapping?

Comment: Please, show us your pom.xml. I cannot reproduce the issue with provided data

Comment: Hi
Added pom.xml as well as logs when tomcat starts in the question itself.

Comment: Try to move the SpringBootMain class to the com.spring package instead of com.spring.boot, (namespaces heriarchy and visibility).

Comment: @Devil: try to return an object or an empty list instead of String, as that will make response type as `plain/text`. which is not rest representation for a resource.

Comment: @Devil, Did you try changing dispatcher-servlet from / to /* ?

Comment: Try changing your `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.spring.controllers"})` to `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.spring.*"})`

Comment: Try adding `@Responsebody` annotation to `gethi` method

Comment: you can also try `@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.spring.controllers")`

Comment: Spring Boot by default scans all children packages. Move SpringBootMain to com.spring and remove the unnecessary scanBasePackages. It will work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot: Cannot access REST Controller on localhost (404)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318107/spring-boot-cannot-access-rest-controller-on-localhost-404)

Answer (score 21):

Your Controller should be in the Child package of SpringBootApplication.
e.g if your SpringbootApplication main method is under com.text.demo package then your Controller class should be under com.text.demo.controller.

or add 
`@ComponentScan("com.text.demo.controller") on Spring boot Application main class.`

Comment: You are the man!
Been strugling with this one hour now.

Answer (score 9):

As people mentioned in the comment try to add your base package.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.spring"})
```

Or

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.spring")
```

But why don't you use this spring initializr https://start.spring.io/ to create a spring boot project from scratch. You can also add any dependency you need.

Here is the mini controller that I tried to reproduce from your example:

**SpringApplication**

```
package com.example.demo.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.example.demo.controller")
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/abc")
    public String getHi() {
        System.out.println("End Point hit");
        return "Hi";
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

and it works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, try calling default actuator endpoints e.g. `http://localhost:8080/error`. They come up with the Spring Boot and will show the actual status of your service.

Answer (score 0):

Change your parent version number to below:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be due to wrong import of @Service annotation. It should be a stereotype one.

Use this in your service class as usage of component scan in Springboot is not a better practice.
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

Answer (score 0):

Go to the pom.xml and add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```