# The request resource is not available - Spring, Hibernate, mvn

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, rest, maven, hibernate-mapping

If we look into the **StudentController**, request mapping is **@RequestMapping("/rest") for class
and get mapping is @GetMapping("/test").**
Hence for url **http://localhost:8080/TestHibernate/rest/test**, I should get a string 'success', which I am not getting.
On executing url **http://localhost:8080/TestHibernate** I am getting the content placed in index file.

Please let me know what part I am missing.

Thank you.

[image]

Controller class

```
    package com.akshay.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.akshay.dao.StudentDAO;
import com.akshay.entity.Student;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentDAO studentDAO;

    @PostMapping("/saveStudent")
    public String save(@RequestBody Student student) {
        studentDAO.saveStudent(student);
        return "Saved Successfully";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        return "Success";
    }
}
```

DAO Layer

```
package com.akshay.dao;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.akshay.entity.Student;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class StudentDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory factory;
    
    private Session getSession() {
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
        if(session == null) {
            session = factory.openSession();
        }
        return session;
    }
    
    public void saveStudent(Student student) {
        getSession().save(student);
    }
}
```

Entity Layer

```
package com.akshay.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    public Student() {

    }

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }
}
```

Entry Point

```
package com.akshay.TestHibernate;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestHibernateApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestHibernateApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

### POM file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.akshay</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestHibernate</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TestHibernate</name>
    <description>Demo project to test hibernate and mysql</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
#
# JDBC connection properties
#
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_student_tracker
jdbc.user=springstudent
jdbc.password=springstudent

#
# Connection pool properties
#
connection.pool.initialPoolSize=5
connection.pool.minPoolSize=5
connection.pool.maxPoolSize=20
connection.pool.maxIdleTime=3000

#
# Hibernate properties
#
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.packagesToScan=com.akshay.entity
```

[image]

Comment: try to remove "TestHibernate" from url and try again. 
And still have problem there please do share your application.pro file

Comment: @solankibhargav I have tried that as well, still getting the same error.
I am uploading the application.properties filr

Comment: Dear @Akshay, I would like to recommend you to narrow the focus of this question down to one problem: HTTP requests do not reach the REST controller.

Answer (score 0):

## Introduction

Let's consider the following versions as the current versions:

- Spring Boot: `2.7.1`.

## Analysis

Please, note that the package of the controller class (`com.akshay.controller.StudentController`) is not the same as the package of the application class (`com.akshay.TestHibernate.TestHibernateApplication`).

Let's refer to the documentation: [Developing with Spring Boot: 6. Using the @SpringBootApplication Annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.1/reference/html/using.html#using.using-the-springbootapplication-annotation):

> Many Spring Boot developers like their apps to use auto-configuration, component scan and be able to define extra configuration on their "application class". A single `@SpringBootApplication` annotation can be used to enable those three features, that is:
>
> - `@EnableAutoConfiguration`: enable [Spring Boot’s auto-configuration mechanism](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.1/reference/html/using.html#using.auto-configuration)
> - `@ComponentScan`: enable `@Component` scan on the package where the application is located (see [the best practices](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.1/reference/html/using.html#using.structuring-your-code))
> - `@SpringBootConfiguration`: enable registration of extra beans in the context or the import of additional configuration classes. An alternative to Spring’s standard `@Configuration` that aids [configuration detection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.1/reference/html/features.html#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.detecting-configuration) in your integration tests.

Please, note:

> - `@ComponentScan`: enable `@Component` scan on the package where the application is located (see [the best practices](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.1/reference/html/using.html#using.structuring-your-code))

## Solution

It is necessary to add the controller package to be component-scanned.

For example:

```
<…>

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.akshay.controller")
public class TestHibernateApplication {

<…>
```

Test the controller method execution by performing an HTTP request:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/rest/test
```

## Additional references

- Stack Overflow question. [java - Spring Boot: Cannot access REST Controller on localhost (404) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318107/spring-boot-cannot-access-rest-controller-on-localhost-404).